# Get column name of selected row jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is there a way for me to get the column name of the selected row on `jqGrid`? For example, on the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5B2Wh/43/

If I clicked on the cell with the content "Merge C", it will return "Client" which is the column name that it is under.

I tried using the code below, but it only sends undefined.

```
var cm = jQuery("#scrgrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
alert(cm.name);
```

Comment: You wrote about "the column name of the *selected row*" and "If I *clicked on the cell*". In which callback you want to have the name of the clicked column: inside of `onCellSelect`, `beforeSelectRow` or `onSelectRow`? You use in the JsFiddle demo very old 4.0 version of jqGrid. Is is the version which you have to use or you can use more recent version like the current 4.4.4 version? The problem is that `onSelectRow` has in version 4.0 **less** parameters as the current version 4.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

`colModel` is an array, you have to select the relevant column from it.

```
$("#scrgrid").jqGrid({
    ...
    onCellSelect: function(row, col, content, event) {
        var cm = jQuery("#scrgrid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
        alert(cm[col].name);
    }
});
```

However, this doesn't work in your grid because you have editing enabled, which disables the ability to select cells.

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
...onCellSelect: function(id,cellidx,cellvalue) {  
    var cm = jQuery("#list").jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
    var colNameAttr = cm[cellidx];
    console.log(colNameAttr.name); //gives column name
}
...
```