# Passing information from one javascript page to another with specific information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am going through the following code of `PeopleReviewPage.js` file where an Ajax request is made and data is populated in the jqxgrid as shown below.
Passing url to the webservice for getting data and many other things are happening behind the scenes which I believe are not relevant to my question and hence not mentioning that. I am trying to relate the onclick 
event defined in `PeopleReviewPage.js` page with the `DocumentDetailsDialog.js` page where I am performing more data related operations.

**PeopleReviewPage.js**

```
// This object is responsible for the "People review" page.
function PeopleReviewPage() {

    var self = this;

    // This maintains state after a cell is clicked and prevents double clicks from triggering an event twice.
    this.cellClicked = false;


    this.urlKey = "showIDNumber";

    // Get data related to IDNumber 
    this.getData = function (IDNumber_) {

        if (isEmpty(IDNumber_)) { alert("Invalid IDNumber in getData()"); return false; }

        // Lookup the AJAX web service URL
        var url = regman.getWebServiceURL(self.urlKey);
        if (isEmpty(url)) { alert("Invalid URL in getData()"); return false; }


        var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
            //beforeSend: TODO: show spinner!
            data: {
                registry_id: regman.registry.id,
                IDNumber: IDNumber_
            },
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            url: url
        })
        .done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {

            // Validate the web service and retrieve the status.
            if (typeof (data_) === "undefined" || data_ === null) { alert("Invalid data returned from web service"); return false; }
            if (isEmpty(data_.webservice_status) || isEmpty(data_.webservice_status.status)) { alert("Invalid web service status"); return false; }
            if (data_.webservice_status.status != "SUCCESS") { alert(data_.webservice_status.message); return false; }

            // Process and display data document data
            self.processdataDocuments(data_.data_document_list);



        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR_, textStatus_, errorThrown_) {
            alert("Error in getData(): " + errorThrown_);
            return false;
        });
    };


    // Initialize the page
    this.initialize = function () {

        // An IDNumber should've been provided by the page that called this page.
        var IDNumber = regman.selectedData["IDNumber"];

        if (isEmpty(IDNumber)) { alert("Invalid IDNumber provided by calling page"); return false; }

        self.getData(IDNumber);


    };


     // Process data document data and dynamically populate the UI.
    // Note that the "collection" parameter should correspond to data_.data_document_list. 

    this.processdataDocuments = function (collection_) {

       var source =
        {
            localdata: collection_,
                datatype: "array"
            };
     var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, {
                loadComplete: function (data) { },
                loadError: function (xhr, status, error) { }
            });
     $("#dataDocumentPanel").jqxGrid(
            {
            source: dataAdapter,
            width: '1000',
                height: 150,
                columns: [
                      {
                          text: 'Type', datafield: 'nc_type'
                      },
                      {
                          text: 'SubType', datafield: 'nc_subtype'
                      },
                      {
                          text: 'Concept', datafield: 'concept_text'
                      },
                      {
                          text: 'Date', datafield: 'nc_dos'
                      }
                  ]
             });

      $("#dataDocumentPanel").on('rowclick',function(event){

           var row = event.args.rowindex;

           var datarow = $("#dataDocumentPanel").jqxGrid('getrowdata', row);
           var jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(datarow,null,10);
           alert(jsonStringify); // This alert displays the JSON data in a formatted manner 
         });

    };
};
```

**DocumentDetailsDialog.js**

```
function DocumentDetailsDialog() {


     var self = this;

    // This maintains state after a cell is clicked and prevents double clicks from triggering an event twice.
    this.cellClicked = false;

    this.urlKey = "showdocument";



    // get data for second url

     this.getData = function (IDNumber_) {

        if (isEmpty(IDNumber_)) { alert("Invalid IDNumber in getData()"); return false; }

        // Lookup the AJAX web service URL
        var url = regman.getWebServiceURL(self.urlKey);
        if (isEmpty(url)) { alert("Invalid URL in getData()"); return false; }


        var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
            //beforeSend: TODO: show spinner!
            data: {
                registry_id: regman.registry.id,
                IDNumber: IDNumber_
            },
            dataType: "json",
            method: "GET",
            url: url
        })
        .done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {

            // Validate the web service and retrieve the status.
            if (typeof (data_) === "undefined" || data_ === null) { alert("Invalid data returned from web service"); return false; }
            if (isEmpty(data_.webservice_status) || isEmpty(data_.webservice_status.status)) { alert("Invalid web service status"); return false; }
            if (data_.webservice_status.status != "SUCCESS") { alert(data_.webservice_status.message); return false; }


            // Process and display data document data
           //self.processNlpDocuments(data_.nlp_document_list);
           var doc_contents = data_.note_content;
            //console.log(doc_contents);

        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR_, textStatus_, errorThrown_) {
            alert("Error in getData(): " + errorThrown_);
            return false;
        });
    };

}
```

**My question:**

When I click on one of the row of jqxgrid, I am able to see all the information of that row in the dialog (`alert(jsonStringify);` defined in the 
PeopleReviewPage is doing that). I am getting the following information using the alert dialog (in JSON) as shown below:

```
"data_document_list" : [ {
    "webservice_status" : null,
    "IDNumber" : "3567973",
    "concept_id" : null,
    "concept_text" : "Multiple Distress",
    "nc_dos" : "2015-07-10",
    "nc_subtype" : "BMT",
    "nc_type" : "HTH"

  }
```

Is there a way from `PeopleReviewPage.js`, I can pass the `nc_subtype` and `IDNumber` related information to the `DocumentDetailsDialog.js` page? Because 
I need to pass `nc_subtype`  and `IDNumber` for the `showdocument` webservice call to get more details about the data document. Please advise.

Comment: TL; DR: You **must** read [ask]!

Comment: @Amit Is there any formatting issue in my question? What does TL; DR means?

Comment: Your question is fine with me are these scripts part of the same page?

Comment: @LeroyThompson Yes basically they are part of the same page. Because, when I will click on a particular row, I will be showing a dialog with data into it. The two files are also in the same folder.

Comment: Ok wherever your calling the function to generate the document replace it with: var PeopleReviewPage = new PeopleReviewPage(); 

Edit this line:  this.dataGrid = $("#dataDocumentPanel").jqxGrid 

Access it with: PeopleReviewPage.dataGrid.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758915/jquery-and-jqgrid-retrieve-data-from-row

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476068/jqgrid-get-all-grids-column-names

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640765/get-column-name-of-selected-row-jqgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used jqGrids but seems like coding work around needs to be done.

Change call function and store it as object: `var PeopleReviewPage = new PeopleReviewPage();`

Edit this line: `.done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {`

Add **this.data** to: `.done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) { 
this.data = data_;`

Access data array object with: `PeopleReviewPage.data`

Example. `PeopleReviewPage.data[0].webservice_status`

> http://jsfiddle.net/d2ee1smd/

Comment: Thanks. I am little bit confused here. I believe you are telling me to edit the line `$("#dataDocumentPanel").jqxGrid` to: `this.dataGrid = $("#dataDocumentPanel").jqxGrid` in `PeopleReviewPage.js` or `DocumentDetailsDialog.js`?  Because `#dataDocumentPanel` is the id related with HTML which I believe is required in `PeopleReviewPage.js`. Also, I am using `jqxgrid` and not `jqgrid` :)

Comment: Ok forget whatever I put earlier, grab the data by inserting 

this.data = data_;

And access it PeopleReviewPage.data

eq. PeopleReviewPage.data[0].webservice_status

Comment: Thanks again. Actually, in `DocumentDetailsDialog.js` page, there is a separate webservice for document defined in the `this.urlKey = "showdocument"`. So, I believe I would only need to use `PeopleReviewPage.data[5]` for `nc_type` as an additional data parameter.

Comment: Something like this may be ` var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
           
            data: {
                registry_id: regman.registry.id,
                mrn: mrn_,
                PeopleReviewPage[5] : nc_type
            },`  Does this looks correct?

Comment: PeopleReviewPage.data[5].nc_type < this is accessing "nc_type"

var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({ data: { registry_id: regman.registry.id, mrn: mrn_, nc_type : PeopleReviewPage.data[5].nc_type }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118851/discussion-between-tan-and-leroy-thompson).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case of *publish/subscrib*, that can be done in jquery with *custom events*.

You should define a custom event from your *PeopleReviewPage* module, where you will fire when you update the data from ajax request for example.

Then create an handler function in the *DocumentDetailsDialog*, that subscribe that event.

So you could have the 2 modules synched but  decoupled.

Here is a trivial example:

```js
$(function(){

 $('.aclass').click(function(ev){
    if (ev.target.tagName == 'INPUT') return false;
   
    var t = $(this).find('input').val();
    $(document).trigger('mycustomevent', [t]);
 });
 
 $(document).on('mycustomevent', function(ev, u){
    var t = $('.bclass').text();
    $('.bclass').text(t + " - " + u);
 });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <span class="aclass">Click me: <input type="text" value="AAAA"/></span>
 <hr/>
 <span class="bclass">BBBB</span>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

To move into your specific case, in your function `PeopleReviewPage()`, in the result of the ajax call:

```
this.getData = function (IDNumber_) {

    ...

   var ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
  ...
   .done(function (data_, textStatus_, jqXHR_) {

      ...

      // Process and display data document data
      self.processdataDocuments(data_.data_document_list);

      // here you trigger the custom event:
      var eventArgs = [data_.data_document_list.nc_subtype, data_.data_document_list.IDNumber];

      $(document).trigger('mycustomevent', eventArgs);

   })
   .fail(function (jqXHR_, textStatus_, errorThrown_) {
      alert("Error in getData(): " + errorThrown_);
      return false;
    });
};
```

Then you need to subscribe the custom event in your other function `DocumentDetailsDialog()`:

```
function DocumentDetailsDialog() {


     ...

     var that = this;

     $(document).on('mycustomevent', function(ev, nc_subtype, IDNumber) {

         // here you can do what you need to do
         // maybe your getData()
         that.getData(IDNumber);

     });

     ...

}
```

I just cut the not need part from your code, and left just the part useful to see where to place the changes.

Like this way you should be able to update the `DocumentDetailsDialog()` each time the `PeopleReviewPage()` is updated, without a deep dependency between the modules.

Please feel free to adapt the code with a proper event name, so change the 'mycustomevent' to something more significant.

You also don't need to use the `document` as the object of your event bus if you have a different and well known DOM element where you could bind the event.

Pay attention to the `that` and `this`, you could use the jQuery [proxy()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function to do it better and use `this` inside the handler function.

Comment: Could you explain how should I go about it with the changes I need to do in my code? Thanks